# What is wrong in this code Vb MySql data to TextBox

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

What is wrong in this code 
I run the software click the button and nothing happens if you have a better code that would help thanks in advance

```
    Dim sql As String
     Dim con As MySqlConnection = New         


   MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=******;Uid=*****;password =******")
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim dataadapter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand()
    Dim datareader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        sql = "SELECT * FROM users"
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        cmd.Connection = con
        dataadapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While datareader.Read
            datareader.Read()
            Email.Text = datareader("Email")
            LastName.Text = datareader("LastName")
            Address.Text = datareader("Address")
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Narrow the scope of your select.  The way its written I think it might set the textbox 100 times if 100 results are returned.  Here is how I would write this:

```
  Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Sub getData()
    Dim objConn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;" _
                                                             & "Database=TestDB;" _
                                                             & "User ID=Root;" _
                                                             & "Password=myPassword;")
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT TOP 1 Email, LastName, Address FROM users"
    Dim da As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        objConn.Open()
        da = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, objConn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Email.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Email").ToString
            LastName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("LastName").ToString
            Address.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Address").ToString
        End If
        da = Nothing
        objConn.Close()
        objConn = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        objConn.Close()
        objConn = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```